# UIStoryboardSegue and WebView

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uiwebview, uistoryboardsegue

I have a storyboard with one ViewController and four UIStoryboardSegue. 
The navigation works perfectly but if I want include a webview into my UIStoryboardSegue, how can I do?
I can't include a viewdidload because it isn't a ViewController.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont segue directly to a webview, you segue to a viewcontroller that contains a web view

so, create a viewcontroller and add a uiwebview to it